# Using Powershell, how can I detect the new line character within the cell of a table is MS Word document

Tags: powershell

I am using Powershell to read a word (2003) document that has a table. The text within the table has new line characters that I need to capture for processing. But when I use Write-host or Write-output the new line character is ignored and the multiple values are printed as if it were one single line.

How can I break on the new line character within the cell? The code I am using is below:

```
$objWord = New-Object -Com Word.Application

$filename = 'C:\Chicago_NewUser.doc'
$objDocument = $objWord.Documents.Open($filename)

$LETable = $objDocument.Tables.Item(1)
$LETableCols = $LETable.Columns.Count
$LETableRows = $LETable.Rows.Count


Write-output "Starting to write... "

for($r=1; $r -le $LETableRows; $r++) {
    for($c=1; $c -le $LETableCols; $c++) {
        #Write-host $r "x" $c
        $content = $LETable.Cell($r,$c).Range.Text
        Write-output $content
    }
}
$objDocument.Close()
$objWord.Quit()
$rc = [System.Runtime.Interopservices.Marshal]::ReleaseComObject($objWord)
```

The word document is available at https://docs.google.com/document/d/1W0usG4ASsvd3PqQ20l7P8rq0hWBsYlrI0iM1S5ZcumU/edit
The value in question is:
SET REG=04
SET BLD=01

But the powershell script prints it as
SET REG=04SET BLD=01

Answered by Self:

I think I figured this out.

I can detect the new line character using this line of code:

```
Write-output $content.contains("`r")
```

Comment: FYI - stackoverflow encourages users to answer their own questions using the answer box.

Comment: I could not. I needed to have a certain minimum points to do that.